# How to create Rails app with Facebook single sign-on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am creating a rails application where I need to allow users to login to my site with their facebook IDs.

How do I do that. I don't understand the facebook documentation much. Are there any other clear resources on the internet?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OmniAuth](http://github.com/intridea/omniauth) is a new kid on the block which looks promising.  It's Rack-based and provides a common API for authentication via Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn et al.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using oauth, here's a ruby tutorial: http://stakeventures.com/articles/2008/02/23/developing-oauth-clients-in-ruby

Comment: I am asking not fo OAuth but for Single Sign On.

Answer (score 0):

Check the pallstrom's code: [fonr](http://github.com/phallstrom/fonr).

[Here](http://facebooker.pjkh.com/) the demo application.

Answer (score 0):

There's a devise plugin too: http://github.com/grimen/devise_facebook_connectable

Answer (score 0):

We just implemented a Facebook Connect using [mini_fb](http://github.com/appoxy/mini_fb) -- it uses the new facebook graph api, which is cool to get data. And if all you're looking for is to login, it's create.

They have an example for facebook_connect and for authentication (to query for data).

Answer (score 0):

For single sign on, you can get a simple copy/paste solution from [LaunchBit](http://toolkit.launchbit.com). It's free.